# PHP printing nested objects with spaces in the name

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, view

I'm trying to print a specific part of the following via Global PHP in a Drupal 7 view field. The parts I want are 'qty' and 'Packet Size -> 2' so the values would be in this case '1' and '5 Packet'.

```
stdClass Object
(
    [_entity_properties] => Array
        (
            [entity object] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [qty] => 1
                    [data] => Array
                            (
                            [attributes] => Array
                                (
                                    [Packet Size] => Array
                                        (
                                            [2] => 5 Packet
                                        )

                                )
```

Now normally, I'd print something like:

```
$data->_entity_properties['entity object']['qty']
```

and

```
$data->_entity_properties['entity object']['data']['attributes']['Packet Size']
```

Which would normally work, but this is not working, and I'm presuming it's to do with the spaces in 'entity object'. Any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try these:

```
$data->_entity_properties['entity object']->qty
$data->_entity_properties['entity object']->data['attributes']['Packet Size']
```

Comment: About an hour of trying no end of variations... perfect! Thank you so much!

Comment: You're welcome! As you see, [entity object] is a "stdClass Object". That was the source of the problem :)

Comment: You're absolutely right. Knew it was the problem... just no idea how to correctly format it. Thanks!